# реализация стека через указатели

Tags: c++

При вводе 0 выводится не число на вершине стека, а какой-то мусор. В чём проблема?

```
#include <iostream>

#define size 50
using namespace std;

void push(int i);
int pop();

int *tos, *p1, stack[size];

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    int value;
    tos = stack;
    p1 = stack;

    do
    {
        cout << "Vvedite chislo:";
        cin >> value;
        if (value != 0) push(value);
        else cout << "Chislo na vershine steka ravno " << pop() << endl;
    } while (value != -1);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void push(int i)
{
    p1++;
    if (p1 == (tos + size))
    {
        cout << "Stek perepolnen" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    *p1 = i;
}

int pop()
{
    if (p1 == tos)
    {
        cout << "Stek ischerpan" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
    p1--;
    return *p1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pop()` не возвращает никакого значения (хотя должен возвращать `int`), приводя к неопределённому поведению.

Comment: подредактировал, возвращает не первое энивей

Comment: @ArtemAleksandrovich А в первое ничего не сохраняется, так до сохранения делается `++p1`.

Comment: нашел проблему,нужно было написать `return *(p1 + 1)`

Comment: @ArtemAleksandrovich Нет, нужно было в функции push сначала записывать значение, а затем уже увеличивать указатель. А так у вас получается попытка скомпенсировать один баг другим.